# Working with HstoreField in django tests

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing, hstore

I'm using HstoreField in one of my models and when I try to test it I got an error `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ERROR: function hstore(integer[], text[]) does not exist`. If I understand this problem correctly it happend because hstore extension wasn't setup in database as it was did in migrations by adding HStoreExtension operation ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield)).

How to setup hstore extension in default test database and solve my problem?

Comment: Do you have a migration that sets up the extension? Do you have the dependenies so that it runs before any migrations that create an `HStoreField`?

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, hstore extension was setted in 12th app's migration file of 15 and everything working fine but tests. And I'm sorry but I didn't understand the second quesion, what do you mean under dependencies?

Comment: I'll try to explain differently. One (or more) of your models uses `HStoreField`. If the migration that creates the first `HStoreField` is migration 13 or more, that's ok because the extension is installed in migration 12. If, say migration 10 creates the first `HStoreField`, then you have a problem, because the extension isn't installed by that point.

Comment: @Alasdair Oh, ok, I understand. Extension installation and first `HStoreField` are in the same migration file, but installation operation was called before creating first `HStoreField`.

Comment: You could try moving the extension installation into an earlier migration.

Comment: @Alasdair No effect(

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you manage to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Simon Charette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70191/simon-charette), who answer this question in [django-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/lXjZnoRT70c):

From the exception it looks like the issue is not related to a missing extension
but from an attempt of using and integer as a key. e.g.

`instance.hstore_field = {1: 'foo'}`
instead of 
`instance.hstore_field = {'1': 'foo'}`

Keys and values in hstore in postgresql are simply text strings ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)) and Django don't convert key object into string. So my HStoreExtension assumption was the wrong way...